# How to add a number in a dict at the end if statement is not true

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to add a number at the end of a value in a `dict`.

My Statement is like this:

```
if (len(mydict['postcode']) < '4':
    mydict['postcode'] = '0'
```

For example, if the postcode is false like :1234
then I'd like to add a 0 at the end like: 12340

Here, I would like to add the number 0 to the end if the postcode is < 5

I tried something like this:

```
if (len(mydict['postcode']) < 5:
    mydict['postcode'][:4] = '0'
```

But I get the error:

```
mydict['postcode'][:4] = '0'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

What is the problem in my code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you share your dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

String type is immutable, thus it can not be changed inplace. What you need to do, is take the original string, and join it with new string. In your case it will be:

```
mydict['postcode'] = mydict['postcode']+'0'

#or shorter version
mydict['postcode'] += '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python, so can't assign a new value to one of the characters. You'd probably have to create a new string and reassign it `mydict['postcode'] += '0'`